# The inherited height of a child div from a parent with a min-height attribute

Tags: cross-browser, css

I'm sorry if this is an old issue or a known problem, but I haven't been able to find an answer online. If I have the code

```
<style>
    html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%;}
    #div1 {height:50%; min-height:200px;background-color:red;}
    #div2 {height:100%; background-color:black;}
</style>
<body>
<div id="div1"><div id="div2"></div></div>
</body>
```

Then in firefox the black inner div shrinks as the screen shrinks and stops at 200px height. However in a webkit browser the red outer div stops but the inner div continue to shrink as if it was in a parent div without the min-height attribute.

Is there an easy fix to bring the webkit version into line with the firefox rendering? A `min-height:inherit` works if placed on the inner div, but in the case of many divs within one this would require `min-height:inherit` on each child div. Are there any more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, this is a WebKit bug, [bug 26559](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26559).

`height` in `%` on static-or-relative-positioned elements is calculated relative to the containing block's stated `height` property, instead of the calculated height taking `min-height` and `max-height` into account. The same does not occur for width.

You can sort of see where this comes from in [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property) which states that the height of a containing block must be explicitly set in order for `%` to work. But it's not explicitly stated what ‘explicitly’ means! Browsers have taken this to mean that the `height` property must be set to a non-auto value, which is fair enough except that `height` isn't all there is to height now. Other browsers allow `min-height`/`max-height` to affect the height to be used, but don't allow it to mean ‘explicit’.  WebKit goes farther (and this definitely isn't mandated by spec) by using *only* `height` in the calcation and not min/max.

As a workaround, you could try absolute positioning, which isn't affected. Relative-position the outer div, absolute-position the inner at `left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's the first time I've found firefox and webkit's rendering to differ and it was driving me up the wall.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the CSS spec; that clears issues up for me. Interestingly, if you specify the child's height as `min-height: 100%` rather than `height: 100%`, it works -- but only in Opera. To my mind, this should be the proper behaviour, but not so, according to the spec. Perhaps someone should file a bug against the spec :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is only the differences between the two browser's default CSS. Try this:

```
<style>
    div {min-height: inherit;}
    #div1 {height:50%; min-height:200px;background-color:red;}
    #div2 {height:100%; background-color:black;}
</style>
```

It works for me.

Comment: Yep that'll do the trick. If you're using span's and other tags you can use `#div1 * {min-height: inherit}` instead. Thank for the answer - it's a better fix than mine was!

Answer (score 1):

Our project needs the image to be vertically and horizontally centered. And we need to make the image adjusted according to the screen size. I find that putting the image as background solve the issue:

```
<style>
    .parent {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .image {
        height: 100%;
        background: url('/path/to/your/image') no-repeat 50% 50%;
        -o-background-size: contain;
        -webkit-background-size: contain;
        -moz-background-size: contain;
        background-size: contain;
    }
</style>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Here `50% 50%` makes the image horizontally and vertically centered. And `background-size: contain` ensures that the background doesn't exceeds the boundary of the parent ([MDN background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)):

> **contain** This keyword specifies that the background image should be
>   scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions
>   are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the
>   background positioning area.
>
> In this way, the parent does not need to specify absolute units. Here
>   `height: 100%` is enough.

**One drawback is: the image will be enlarged to fill in the parent space.**

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with min-height on an empty div in Chrome (OSX 10.6).
I don't know if it's the same bug behavior but I **found my solution with changing the box-sizing attribute**.

**Not working in Chrome Mac:**

```
box-sizing:border-box;
min-height:10px;
padding-bottom:15px;
padding-top:30px;
```

**Working in Chrome Mac:**

```
box-sizing:content-box;
min-height:10px;
padding-bottom:15px;
padding-top:30px;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post my solution as it took me a while to make my code work and perhaps somebody will find this useful despite the fact that this is an old topic...

I had a simillar problem. An image was overflowing from a parent flex-child block. This happened only in Chrome and Opera (webkit browsers), trident and gecko were smart enough to deal with the situation. I tried a few solutions here on stack overflow but none provided a direct solution so I have cross-invented a workaround by adding another container layer in between aforementioned image and parent. In the situation presented at the opening post it would look like:

```
<style>
    html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%;}
    #div1 {height:50%; min-height:200px;background-color:red; position: relative;}
    #div_fix {position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%;}
    #div2 {height:100%; background-color:black;}
</style>
<body>
<div id="div1"><div id="div_fix"><div id="div2"></div></div></div>
</body>
```

What this does is create a container (#div_fix) that receives static height and width that then can be properly used in webkit to calculate correct height in #div2.
Please note that position:relative and position:absolute properties are mandatory for it to work.

And yes, it looks bad, but gets the job done :)