# Why do height and min-height affect the child container differently?

Tags: html, css

In my css, I have the height of the parent set to 75px, and the height of the child set to 100%, and it displays correctly. However, when I change the parent's height attribute to a min-height of 75px instead, the child shrinks to the height of the text it contains, but the parent's height stays 75px. Why doesn't the child stay 75px?

```
#parent{
    height:75px;
    background-color:navy;
    clear:left;
    }
#child{
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:aqua;
    float:left;
    }
```

Here, the child is 75px like it is supposed to be.

```
#parent{
    min-height:75px;
    background-color:navy;
    clear:left;
}
#child{
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:aqua;
    float:left;
    }
```

The child is only 21px high now.

Comment: in order to use a percentage height, the child's parent element must be concretely defined (e.g., a px value) -- min-height doesn't count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has been a longstanding bug (or 'feature') in CSS. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808701/1608085

In short, you can use

```
min-height: inherit;
```

in the child to correctly inherit the min-height property from the parent.

Comment: I hadn't considered that work-around; nicely done! And welcome to Stack Overflow! =)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem.