# Why do min/max width/height values don't allow the element to fill out its parent div?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="card">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    min-height: 350px;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 350px;
    padding: 15px;
}

.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aJhEF/1/

When examined with console, it shows that `.content` has functioning width and height. Then why does the child element, with its width and height being set to 100% not fill out its parent's width and height?

Comment: You need to give it an explicit width/height, rather than only minimum and maximum values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Child elements don't inherit their parents `min-height` property

This is why the .card element has a height of 0

As far as width is concerned, .card **does** fill out it's parent's width.

Comment: This seems like strange behaviour. Do you know why they don't inherit min-height property?

Comment: It does not fill out it's parent as long as the padding is there. Padding is extra space on the INSIDE of the parent element, therefore this extra space is non-filled space of the parent element.

Comment: @styke After some googling I found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3808701/703717) - :)

Comment: @Danield thanks Daniel, the post you found contains a workaround too. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

Danield is right.

You might solve this by using relative and absolute positions, combined with a negative margin (to compensate the padding):

```
.content {
    min-height: 350px;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 350px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you gave the parent a set padding.
Remove `padding: 15px;` to fill out the div.

padding is extra space at the inside of the elements borders. If you want space around the outside, use margin.

You stated that you wanted your child to fill out the parent element, and since padding it is extra space on the inside of the parent element, the child will not fill out it's parent as long as the padding is there.

**Edit:** The reason you don't see the results you wanted is because you have your element a min-height and min-width instead of actual sizes. You need to give this element set size (be it pixels or %). This is due to the fact that your child element doesn't inherit the min and max width/height of it's parent.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJhEF/2/)

Comment: I've noticed if you remove the `min` prefixes, it fills it out, sans padding.